# Selecting Drop Down values programmatically

Tags: php, screen-scraping

This is the URL I am working on

```
http://www.bkstr.com/CategoryDisplay/10001-9604-10311-1?demoKey=d
```

These are the drop down values:

Select Your Program: All (a constant)

Select Your Term: Spring 2012 (a constant))

Search By Course ID or Select Your Department: Contains a list of values (I need to choose this value one by one from my program)

The next drop down "Search By Course ID or Select Your Course" will appear based on what we select in the previous drop down.

This the part that I am trying to automate.

Well, upon clicking submit I get the URL

```
http://www.bkstr.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CourseMaterialsResultsView?catalogId=10001&categoryId=9604&storeId=10311&langId=-1&programId=755&termId=100021416&divisionDisplayName=%20&departmentDisplayName=ADV&courseDisplayName=3001&sectionDisplayName=10182&demoKey=d&purpose=browsea
```

Here I can see the chosen values getting passed as query parameters but then this leaves me with a problem:

- Every time some new value is added to the drop down list, I have to change my code to incorporate that value

How can I programatically (dynamically) loop through the Department & it's subsequent Courses WITHOUT hardcoding the values prior in my query parameter? Any guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to "echo" the list courses from the database to the page in the form of a a JS array which corresponds to the index of your department. note that arrays start counting from 0 so your department values should also be starting with 0. this piece of code should be on the head of your html.

```
var courses = [
    ["course1-1","course1-2","course1-3","course1-4","course1-5"],
    ["course2-1","course2-2","course2-3","course2-4","course2-5"],
    ["course3-1","course3-2","course3-3","course3-4","course3-5"]
];
```

then, with javascript, add an event listener for your `<select>`. say you have this HTML

```
<select id="departments">
    <option value="0">dept1</option>
    <option value="1">dept2</option>
    <option value="2">dept3</option>
</select>

<select id="courses"></select>
```

for jQuery, your listener will be like this. it should get the previous select value and based on that, build another select.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


function setCourses() {
    var departmentValue = $('#departments').val();
    var courseOptions = "";
    for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
        courseOptions += "<option value=" + i + ">" +courses[departmentValue][i] + "</option>";
    }
    $("#courses").html(courseOptions);
}

$('#departments').change(function() {
    setCourses();
});

setCourses();

});
```

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z5GTX/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use Selenium RC, assuming you have access to a server with a GUI (it doesn't need to be the same server as the one executing the PHP). There is a PHP version, which you can use to open a browser and simulate clicks and other interactions with the page.

http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/

If you don't have access to a  server with a GUI, you'll need to do server-side JavaScript with something like Rhino or NodeJS.